# The divs width add up to less than 100%

Tags: html, css

I need to align two divs in the same line and set the first one `width: 100px;`

I want to set the second div `width: calc(100% - 100px);` Then the div will go to next line. I have to do a `100% - 102px` so that the two divs can stay in the same line.

My question is why the two divs' width don't add up to 100%? It's always one or two pixel less.

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
}
.first-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
.second-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="first-div">First Div</div>
  <div class="second-div">Second Div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create an MVCE with the relevant code as a code snippet.

Comment: Do you have a border?

Comment: Add your markup and stylesheet code as well to make your question more mature.

Comment: @furbar I added a snippet. The first div's width and second div's width add up to 100%. But the second div will go to the next line.

Comment: @jhpratt You mean the border isn't included in width? I didn't set any border though.

Comment: @Viv See my answer. Classic problem, really. And no, border is _not_ included unless you specify `box-size: border-box`

Comment: @jhpratt ok. Your answer does help me a lot! The whitespace thing sounds basic but I never knew it before. The only problem is that my codes all squeeze together after remove all the whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see exactly where you've gone wrong. Remember that whitespace has a width! Newlines are whitespace too, and this collapses down to a single space.

The solution is quite simple — comment out the whitespace. Alternatively, you could put the two `div`s on the same line.

Here's the first solution.

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
}
.first-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
.second-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="first-div">First Div</div><!--
  --><div class="second-div">Second Div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a CSS reset stylesheet. Or else, you could be seeing the browser's built-in padding.

Answer (score -1):

Thats because of your 102px you are subtracting from 100%. 
A little math:
If 100% is let's say 1000px :
You say that the one div should be 100px. 
Everything fine till now. But then: 100% - 102px means in this case: 1000px - 102px = 898px . If you now add the width of the first div to the second you get:
898px + 100px = 998px. This is of course not 100%.